# How often should internal applications be deployed?

Tags: testing, deployment, release-management

**In Short:**

Should I deploy each fix/feature as I make it, or schedule releases for an internal application?

**Some Background:**

A few months ago I was hired as our IT's first dedicated developer with the ultimate goal of developing an application to replace a 10 year old internal tool that is used multiple times a day by about 20-30 staff within the office (out of maybe 50-60 in total).  The first months were spent getting to know the application as it exists currently: fixing bugs, adding features from the backlog, and integrating web services we want present in version 2.0.

Staff are right there to let me know when they need a little fix/tweak and when something has gone horribly wrong.  For the latter case, I obviously squash the bug and deploy the application asap.  As we are now ready to begin development of its replacement, my question is around how to handle the small fixes/features that we'll continue to support over this development cycle.

When I came on as the dedicated developer for this, I was able to implement multiple web-services and additional automations to enhance the application rather quickly, and fixes could be done within a day (as opposed to whenever our head of IT had time to take a break from other duties).

**The Problem:**

My fear is that the expectation is starting to be created that tweaks can be done and pushed out the same day. Even if I can fix a small bug or add a small feature and deploy within an hour that could be perpetuating the habit of walking up to my desk and staff saying "Can we move x to this side of the page by tomorrow?"

**The Question:**

Assuming these internal applications can be easily deployed, how often should I deploy them?  I've tried to implement release versions (for my own sanity) and am considering a once-a-week max (except for breaking bugs) deployment. Is that appropriate? What are the other constraints on release schedule I should consider?

Comment: This completly depends on you. Answers to this question will be highly opinionated. It will range from _release several times each day_ to _release all 6 months_ (or so). The only thing we can say to you is take any approach and make it fit to you (e.g. Agile means release often/release early).

Comment: @Uwe Plonus, I suspected as much.  Between my supervisor and I we've both only got personal experience to go.  Just wondering if there was general practice about this.

Comment: I'm in a pretty similar situation here. For me it is pretty easy to deploy so I do when ever I have something. In case it was something requested by a user I let him know to restart the software to get the update. This way if the user want the new thing right now he can restart else the next day he will have it since they are suposed to turn off computer at night.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**

Comment: _Even if I can fix a small bug or add a small feature and deploy within an hour that could be perpetuating the habit of walking up to my desk and staff saying "Can we move x to this side of the page by tomorrow?"_ I'm not trying to be rude or sarcastic but... isn't this your job? If it is, then I think you should implement practices such as continuous integration/deployment. You would not only be adding value to the app, but you'll be making things easier for yourself. I could explain these in much more detail but if it isn't your job to mantain the app, perhaps it would not be helpful.

Comment: @Hernan, thanks for the comment.  As we are shifting priorities to replacing this application, we do not want to stop improving the existing application entirely since it will be a few months before we are ready to stop using the current format. Trying to strike that balance of support and tempering expectations of staff on how much time we will be dedicating to the current format.  Sounds like your vote is release each time and I appreciate the feedback.  Still getting my feet wet.

Comment: Those of you who are suggesting [Continuous Delivery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) as a solution need to be reminded that *this isn't a large corporate body.* It's just the OP and 20 users.

Comment: @MattN. You are talking about a rewrite and the expectations of users. Because likely the rewrite will take time. So it will delay those smaller fixes users want. Now I don't want to bother you with the whole discussion but if this system works: Why don't you just keep bug fixing and improving?

Comment: @LucFranken It's a 10 year old "application" that has been patched together to augment a largely paper-based workflow over a few different applications actually.  We're making a move to paperless and point-of-need printing.  We need to create new interfaces to handle the work tasks and rather than maintain 3-4 separate apps we'd like to bring it all together.  We're refactoring some, but a lot of the code will be reused.

Comment: Ask yourself the reverse question and you might find the answer for your particular situation. What do you have to gain by delaying releases? Do you have to run some time consuming validation regression testing before a release? If so, then getting more fixes in before a release is more efficient, so periodic releases is a logical choice. If not, then what's the point of delaying if the code is just going to essentially "sit-there". Might as well get people using it and testing it for you ASAP.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Just because Amazon, Facebook or Google use continuous delivery doesn't mean that it works _only_ on corporate environments with hundreds of users. I'm currently developing an app for ~30 users and every bug fix or feature generate a new release. From `git push` to deployment on Tomcat built using Jenkins as CI server. It's not that difficult from a technical point of view, and you'd be surprised to see that the crappy PC where Jenkins is running is still working. So setting up the environment isn't expensive. Although I admit that it might not be suitable for every situation.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it less a generic "best practices" question and one more amenable to answering with specific data and experience. I have been in the asker's shoes, and it seems a very relevant "how should I manage releases?" question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the world of commercial software, release schedules are tied to:

1. Development timeline (How long does it take to create each release or patch?)
2. Testing and QA timeline (How long does it take to test, qualify, and certify the app as running properly on all the platforms and in all the modes in which it will typically be used; this often includes "integration," "stress," and "acceptance" testing, not just unit tests)
3. Sales and marketing cycles (How long does it take to create demand for, or acceptance of, the new release?)
4. Customer update cycles (How often do customers want new releases? And at what point in their business cycles can they accept new releases/features? Retailers, e.g., lock down all non-urgent upgrades throughout the entire multi-month "Christmas season")
5. Training and support integration (How long does it take to document new features/fixes, train both internal and end-users on them, and get your support team up to speed on the changes?)

Traditionally releases are a Big Deal, for both the software developer and the customers. So release cycles of 1-3 years between "major" releases have been common, with "minor" or "dot" releases every 3-6 months, and emergency patches on an as-needed basis.

Cloud and SaaS (software as a service) shops are the opposite extreme, they often "slipstream" updates without ever telling anyone (maybe their support staff, but not always even then). I know shops that do updates once a week, on a fixed day. Others update as often as several times daily.

You're a small shop with an internal app, so there's no real sales/marketing cycle. There doesn't seem to be any official support or testing/QA function between users and development. Your development cycles seem short, and your deployments easy. So you could iterate as fast as your user community will let you.

Having been in this situation, some suggestions:

1. Just because you don't have an official testing/QA organization doesn't mean you should avoid testing. Please, please, please have an automated testing suite that you run before every release. This can save you a world of hurt later.
2. Just because you can silently "slipstream" new functions or patches doesn't mean you should. In fact, you should not. Have a real version or release number on EVERY release. This will make tracking down bugs easier. (See e.g. [semantic versioning](http://semver.org) for insight on a structured way to assign release numbers.)
3. Have an app web page or "about this app" screen that shows recent version updates. Showing users what is "new and notable" is one of the things fast-updated open source projects have learned helps increase user trust and comfort with the update process.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking the wrong question.

»How often should internal applications be deployed« has many implications which are disadvantageous - e.g. if you have a release-cycle - say 1 week - there are perhaps small but important changes, which have to wait 6.x days to the next release.

It would be a better practice to release as often as you have something to release: which could sometimes be once every two days or twice a day; depending on your workflow. If you have features, which aren't tested enough, you could implement *feature-toggles* (e.g. configuration values in a DB which *de-/activates* features). So you could easily roll out to production. And if you realize, that the new feature doesn't behave the way you wanted, you could roll back as fast as you toggle the featureswitch.

> My fear is that the expectation is starting to be created that tweaks can be done and pushed out the same day.

Why should that be a problem?
If you can do the fix, why wait to release it?

> Even if I can fix a small bug or add a small feature and deploy within an hour that could be perpetuating the habit of walking up to my desk and staff saying "Can we move x to this side of the page by tomorrow?"

Same question: Why is that a problem?

The only problem you have is *communication*.
You have to earn credibility: If you say, it could be fixed within 10 Minutes and you push it to production in 10 minutes everything will be fine. But on the other hand, if you say it takes 5 days, you should have so much credibility, that everyone knows, that it takes 5 days. You are in charge, you set the deadlines. And you are responsible to communicate that.
This is oftentimes a painful process for both sides - but in the end: both sides win.
As a professional, you have to communicate, how long something takes. Management doesn't write software, users do not write software, you write software.

> What can I expect to see as I continue in my career in terms of internal applications? Are there best practices for deployment of internal tools? Are they treated any differently?

I can not foresee, where you are going. But in some parts of the industry, what I described vaguely is known as a process called *continous deployment* and gains more and more attention.

Comment: I disagree with a large portion of this.  Feature toggles are an expensive strategy, for many reasons.  So is continuous deployment; such an effort would have to be undertaken carefully, with certain controls to assure business process integrity.  Management of expectations is more important than you think it is; people asking for changes every five minutes because they have come to expect them is a genuine problem, not a hypothetical one.

Comment: Yes, you are right: managing expectations is the most important point. And it is all about communication. You have to communicate, what is possible and what not and at which velocity. If the management comes up every five minutes with new wishes, it is, your job in the first place, to communicate  whether and how their wishes could become true.  And after that, do your job.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the answer will be entirely dependent on how painful (or painless) it will be to upgrade 30 people to the newer version.

The easier you make it to upgrade, the better off you will be with a rapid release schedule. The more painful it is, the more you will benefit from a regular release schedule.

It's completely up to you.

Comment: Pretty painless.  Applications live on our network drives and updating dlls and such is usually not an issue. It's just a matter of them restarting the application.

Comment: @MattN. then I suppose you have your answer.

Comment: The issue isn't the work it takes to push out the update, it's managing the expectations of the employees who use it.

Comment: @MattN. which, as I stated very clearly, is strongly tied to the effort in which it will take to update 30 people. If it's a pain in the a**, don't do it very often. If it is dirt simple, do it whenever it is convenient. The decision is **up to you**, and making that decision is probably in your job description.